# SSIS - debugging not working

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

Recently started using Visual Studio 2012, converting SSIS packages from 2008, and seem to be unable to set breakpoints in Script Tasks.  The error we're receiving says

> Cannot start debugging.  Pre-debugging negotiations with Host failed.

Cannot seem to find any information about this error, or what's causing it.  There is also a brief flash of a dialog box that says

> Visual Studio has encountered an unexpected error

but that disappears quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The input parameters were set incorrect and hence was failing. It has been fixed now

Comment: Upvoted this, because that was the exact same problem i had!

Answer (score 0):

I think you install new version of Visual Studio you just have to uninstall the Visual Studio tools for Application for the new version then repair the Visual Studio tool for Application 2012 and every thinks will be good